# com.rey.material.widget.SnackBar - The text into it appears on the top

Tags: android, material-design, android-snackbar, snackbar

When I show the snackbar the text appears on the top. I'm talking about the text, not the snackbar. The next picture shows this behaviour:

[image]

I'm using the library of **com.rey.material.widget** (https://github.com/rey5137/Material/wiki/SnackBar), and this is the piece of code I'm dealing with:

```
SnackBar.make(this)
  .singleLine(true)
  .text("This is a message")                                                                   
  .textColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white_text_color))
  .duration(getResources().getInteger(R.integer.snackbar_dismiss_timer))
  .show(this);
```

What can I do? Any clue? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried using the [official Snackbar[(http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/Snackbar.html), part of the [Android Design Support Library](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html)?

Comment: It's like a bug, i'd rather to use default snakebar with default android library.and also, i would rather to open an issue for that library on github too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I **HIGHLY** recommend you to use standard `com.android.support` library. I worked around one hour to fix this problem and I give up. I'm sure that it's definetely problem with a library.

I tried:

- `.setPadding()` - no matter what values you would add text wouldn't be seen
- `.textAppearence()` - the same situation
- `.setForeground()` - as above

Actually, I don't see any new option, that hasn't been already tested

To see how buggy it is, use code like below:

```
    SnackBar.make(this)
            .singleLine(true)
            .text("This is a message")
            .textColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary))
            .duration(2000)
            .backgroundColor(R.color.colorAccent)
            .textAppearance(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER)
            .show();
```

[I won't tell you what you would see, just give a try]

Sorry, but there's no reason to use this library instead of great `MaterialDesign` lib, as it has that kind of problems and it needs libs, that already have standard `Snackbar` library.

If you still think that `Google's Snackbar` is not an option, have a look at these alternatives: http://android-arsenal.com/tag/234

Hope it help

Comment: That not worked for me, but taking into account your insistence on use the official design library I decided include it on my implementation. Thanks for provide a direct answer to the issue and you advice. Thank you!